# 7zip archive multiple files with their respective names

Tags: shell-script, archive, p7zip

I have lots of files that I want to archive/compress using 7zip utility. They all reside in the same folder.
Each archive must have the same name as the file that is to be archived.

For example, if the files are `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt` then the archives should be `1.7z`, `2.7z` and so on.

I have found some batch scripts, but I need a bash script.

I can list all the files using

```bash
for i in *.txt; do echo $i; done
```

but cannot make it work with 7zip command, i.e. `7z a 'archive.7z' 'file.txt'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
for i in *.txt; do 7z a "${i%%.*}.7z" "$i"; done
```

This command seems to work. If your file name contains spaces, then try setting the delimiter to line-break. I achieved it by using this command `IFS=$'\n'`.

`${i%%.*}` this thing was used to remove the extension `.txt` in my case. If you want your archive to look like this `.txt.7z` then simply use `$i.7z` and it will work.

Comment: How can you extract the filename only from this so that the file destination can be defined as a different location?

Comment: Figured it out.  `for i in /path/to/input/files/*; do f=$(basename -- "$i"); 7z a "/path/to/outout/files/$f.7z" "$i"; done`